# Defining a ScalaCheck generator in terms of another Gen

Tags: scala, scalacheck

How do I define a generator in to produce random data for `fields` of a given `Block`. Following is the scaffolding code. I need help with an expression to replace the `???`. This expression should generate `Seq[Field]`, but the `Field` should be generated using defined `genField` function.

```
def blockGen(b: Block): Gen[Block] = for {
    id <- b.blockId //Use the same blockId as b
    fields <- ??? //Get the type from each field and call genField
} yield Block(id, fields)
```

**ADT**

```
trait Data {}

trait Field extends Data {
  val name: String
  val value: String
}

case class StringField(name: String, value: String) extends Field
case class NumberField(name: String, value: String) extends Field
case class Block(blockId: Field, fields: Seq[Field]) extends Data
```

**Generators**

```
def fieldGen(fieldType: Field): Gen[Field] = {
  for {
    f <-
    fieldType match {
      case _: NumberField => numGen
      case _: StringField => strGen
    }
  } yield f
}

val strGen: Gen[StringField] = for {
  name <- Gen.identifier
  value <- Gen.alphaStr
} yield StringField(name, value)

val numGen: Gen[NumberField] = for {
  name <- Gen.identifier
  value <- Gen.numStr
} yield NumberField(name, value)
```

**Sample Block: myBlock**

```
val cx = new StringField("blockId", "CX")
val seg = StringField("segmentation", "ABC")
val ver = NumberField("version", "1.0")

val myBlock = Block(cx, Seq(seg, ver))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is `Gen.sequence`.

Also, `id` doesn't need to come from a generator, since all you're doing is using a particular value directly.

```
def blockGen(b: Block): Gen[Block] =
  for {
    fields <- Gen.sequence[Seq[Field], Field](b.fields.map(fieldGen))
  } yield Block(b.blockId, fields)
```

By the way, `Gen.sequence` is very similar to [`Future.sequence`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$) and [`sequence` in Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:sequence).

Comment: i wonder why I can't see the sequence function in scaladoc: https://www.scalacheck.org/files/scalacheck_2.11-1.13.1-api/index.html#org.scalacheck.Gen

Comment: This is an extremely poor design of scaladoc that confuses everyone: click on the "C" in the top-left corner (that stands for "class") and it will change to "O" (for "object") showing the methods on the [companion object](https://www.scalacheck.org/files/scalacheck_2.11-1.13.1-api/index.html#org.scalacheck.Gen$).

Comment: Got it "O" vs "C". Had I known this, I might have tried harder solving this :-).